An $L^p-L^{p}$ inequality
This question has been reposted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482601/a-proof-for-an-lp-lp-inequality
Please, post your answer there.
Let $a\in (0,1)$. Assume that $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is  continuously differentiable such that $$|f|\leq 1,\qquad (1)$$
$$x\mapsto\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt\quad \text{is an}\;L^{p}([0,\infty))\; \text{function}.\qquad (2)$$
Consider the inequality
$$\left\|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(t x) f^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt\right\|_{L^{p}([0,\infty)}\leq C  \left\|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt\right\|_{L^{p}([0,\infty)}.\qquad (*)$$
It is easy to come up with a sequence $(f_{n})$ of  functions differentiable except at a finite number of points at which the function has jump discontinuities  and satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$, such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left\|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f_n(t x) f_n^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt\right\|_{L^{p}([0,\infty)}}{\left\|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f_n^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt\right\|_{L^{p}([0,\infty)}}=\infty.\qquad (**)$$
Take for instance
$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\chi_{[2\pi k,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k]}(x)\sin{x}+\chi_{[\pi+2\pi k,\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k]}(x)\sin{x}.\qquad (3)$$
or take for that matter
$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\chi_{[2k,2 k+1)}(x)(x-2k)-\chi_{[2k+1,2k+2])}(x) (x-2k-1).\qquad (4)$$
The idea is that $f^{\prime}_{n}$ oscillates (changes sign) periodically while the product $f_{n}f^{\prime}_{n}$ stays positive.

Is it possible to construct a counterexample for $(*)$ ? Precisely does there exist a sequence of continuously differentiable functions that satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$ for which the inequality $(1)$ does not hold ?

The difficulty here is that, if the derivative $f^{\prime}$ is continuous, it is impossible to have $ff^{\prime}>0$ all the time. Indeed, between every two zeros of $f$ there is a zero of $f^{\prime}$ (i.e. $f$ can stay positive or stay negative while $f^{\prime}$ changes sign from positive to negative or the converse at least once).
Observe that, by Minkowski's integral inequality, $f^{\prime}\in L^{p}([0,\infty))$ for some $p>1$ is sufficient for $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f_n^{\prime}(t x)}{(1-t)^{a}}dt$ to be in $L^{p}([0,\infty))$. Add the condition $f^{\prime}\in L^{p}([0,\infty))$ for the moment. It is tempting to approximate the derivatives $f_{n}^{\prime}$ of $f_{n}$, in a sequence such as $(3)$ or (4), in $L^{p}([0,\infty))$, by smooth functions. But then we are left with $f_{n}$. Are we not ? And we can not use approximation of Sobolev functions either since $f_{n}$ in $(3)$ does not have a weak derivative because of its jump discontinuities.
May be I am wrong and the inequality $(*)$ does hold true for continuously differentiable functions that satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$. A proof of that would be great.

An update: I tried mollifying the derivative $f^{\prime}_{n}$ of $f_{n}$ in both (3) and (4) by convolution with the approximate identity $x\mapsto n e^{-n*\pi x^2}$. Then I integrated to compute $f_{n}$. Mathematica was used in all  calculations. The test failed, meaning the inequality $(*)$ seems to hold after approximating $f_n$ and $f^{\prime}_n$ by smooth functions as described in the test.
